# Android:How to use Class<? extends Activity> as a variable type in Parcelable

Tags: android, class, parcelable

I'm having problem about writing and reading a variable whose type is `Class<? extends Activity>` but I could find any solution for this.

clas is variable name whose type is `Class<? extends Activity>`. I'm using this variable for opening related activity, when an student clicked in a listactivity

There is no function like `Parcelable.readClass()` or `writeClass()` can anyone help please to solve this

Thx in advance

Here is my `Student.java`

```
public class Student {
    private String id;
    private Class<? extends Activity> clas;

    ...

}
```

Here I created `ParcalebleStudent.java`

```
public class ParcalebleStudent implements Parcelable {
    private Student student;

    ....

    private ParcalebleStudent(Parcel in) {
        student = new Student();
        student.setId(in.readString());
        student.setClas(in.readWhat?????????);//I need help here
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeString(student.getId());
        parcel.writeWhat???????(student.getClas());//and here

    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why is `clas` type `Class`?  Are you saying that `clas` could be a reference to **any** object?

Comment: Sorry I edited my question now, and yes clas could be a reference to any object that extends activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `parcel.writeString(student.getClas().getName());` and `student.setClas(Class.forName(in.readString());`

Answer (score 1):

`Class` is Serializable, so you could use `writeSerializable` and `readSerializable`.  You'll then have to cast it back to `Class<? extends Activity>`. Most IDEs will give you an unsafe cast warning, but there's not a great way to do it in a manner where you avoid that warning.